# Find, the marginal functions of $f(x,y)=\min\left \{x,y \right \}{1}_{(0,1)^2}$

Tags: probability, statistics

$$f(x,y)=\min\left \{x,y \right \}{1}_{(0,1)^{2}}$$

Help, how to integrate with respect to each variable....

$$f_X(x)=\int_0^1 \min\{x,y\} \, dy $$

$$f_{X}(x)=\int_0^1 y \, dy+\int_0^1 x \, dy= \frac12+x$$

Would this be correct?

I just want to know if my limits are correct

Comment: Do not deface your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not. If $y<x$ then $f=y$ and $f=x$ if $x<y$. Integrate over all the support of $Y$:

$$
f_X = \int_0^x y \, dy + \int_x^1 x \, dy
$$
You can solve the integrals on your own. If not let me know

Comment: Thank you very much friend

Comment: One does not "solve" expressions; one _solves_ equations; one _solves_ problems; one _evaluates_ expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. English is not my mother tongue so I incorrectly did a direct translation